# Dynamically Load Vue Component from a variable

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vue-component

I was building a very large enterprise application where components load on demand , i use to work with require.js and i am able to do `require(stringVar){..}`

but i am not able to do this in webpack i thought webpack was better in everything

```
var URL ="./components/async.vue";
      console.log(typeof(URL));
      Vue.component("async", function(resolve) {
        // Master Loader
        require([URL], resolve);
      });
```

everything i change the value of `require(["./components/async.vue"], resolve);` to  `require([URL], resolve);` it throws

```
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

Comment: does this `require` belong to ES6 or require.js (AMD) ?

Comment: ES6, that cames with vue-cli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Solved the problem using Webpack context dependency management

var Dynamic_address = "./component/myfirstcomp.vue";

require("./template/" + Dynamic_address + ".vue");

https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-context

Answer (score 0):

I do this a lot in our app though NOT in this specific way. However, I think `resolve` should send back the component's definition.

You c(/sh)ould try:

```
resolve(require(URL))
```

DOUBT: Is `URL` mentioned above a resource hit on the server / just relative path between the two components ?

Comment: The `require` used above is the ES6 version (or import) and NOT AMD `require`.

Comment: believe me you cannot do resolve(require(URL)) if URL is a variable not a static value like "./comp.....", you have to explicitly hard core the value otherwise webpack fails..

Comment: Just curious: `require(prefix + 'url' + suffix)` did not work for you ?

Comment: i just came from require.js to webpack.js, and its confusing if you apply one concept to another. but thanks anyways i have no idea about that before